# Can someone help me with C

Tags: c

Write a program in C that:
declares a string variable called buffer with maximum size 80
inputs a string from the keyboard into the buffer
modifies the string contained in buffer by replacing any vowels (upper or lower case 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o' or 'u') with a plus sign (+)
prints out the modified string
prints out the total number of vowels that were replaced

i did this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[80];
    char word[80];
    char word2[80];
    scanf("%s",word);
    strcpy(buffer, word);

   int i;
   int counter=0;
   for(i=0;i<80;i++)
   {
      word2[i]="";
   }

   for(i=0;i<strlen(buffer);i++)
   {
   if(buffer[i]=="a" || buffer[i]=="e" || buffer[i]=="i" || buffer[i]=="o" || buffer[i]=="u" || buffer[i]=="A" || buffer[i]=="E" || buffer[i]=="I" || buffer[i]=="O" || buffer[i]=="U")
  //   if(strcmp(buffer[i],"a")==0)
      {
          strcat(word2,"+");
          counter++;
      }else{
       strcat(word2,buffer[i]);
      }
   }

   printf("The modified string is %s",word2);
   printf("in total there was %d vowels.",counter);

   return 0;
}
```

But i keep on getting an error, please help me.

Comment: The second **for** statement is incomplete.

Comment: For such problems, always include the exact error message(s) in the question.

Comment: I see three compiler problems: 1) the line starting with: `if(buffer[i]=="a" ||`  where all the string literals, like "a", should be: 'a'.  2) this line: `strcat(word2,buffer[i]);` is passing a single char for the second parameter. both parameters have to be pointers. suggest: `strncat(word2,&buffer[i, 1]);`  3) this line: `word2[i]="";` is trying to assign a pointer to a char.  suggest: `word2[i]='\0';`

Comment: when calling `scanf()` (or any of the scanf() family of functions)  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' format specifier with `scanf()` always include a length modifier that is 1 less than the size of the input buffer.  Otherwise the user can overflow the input buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the code block, beginning with: `for(i=0;i<80;i++)` can be eliminated by declaring `word2[]` as: `char word2[80] = {'\0'};`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}',  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with variable width fonts.  Never use tabs for indenting as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, so the variable 'i' should be declared as `sizeo_t i;`  not `int i;`,   The line: `for(i=0;i<strlen(buffer);i++)` is calling the function `strlen()` over and over and over.  The function `strlen()` is expensive in CPU cycles.  suggest: size_t length = strlen(buffer);  for( i=0; i<length; i++ )

Answer (score 3):

You need to use single quotes for characters:

```
buffer[i]=='a'
```

`"a"` represents a pointer to a string literal that would be stored in some segment of the program's address space.

Comment: In addition, I would recommend replacing that giant if-statement with `if( strchr("aeiouAEIOU", buffer[i]) ) ...`, or `if( strchr("aeiou", tolower(buffer[i])) ) ...`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[80];
    char word[80];
    char word2[80];
    scanf("%s",word);
    strcpy(buffer, word);

    int i;
    int counter=0;


    for(i=0;i<strlen(buffer);i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i]=='a'|| buffer[i]=='e' || buffer[i]=='i' || buffer[i]=='o' || buffer[i]=='u' || buffer[i]=='A' || buffer[i]=='E' || buffer[i]=='I' || buffer[i]=='O' || buffer[i]=='U')
        {
           word[i] = '+';
           counter++;
        }

    }

    printf("The modified string is %s",word);

    printf("in total there was %d vowels.",counter);

    return 0;

}
```